# How to render a template from a json using underscore.js

Tags: html, json, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I was wondering how to render a json object as a underscore template: below is my json data:

```
 $('#testinfoWidget').testInfo({   // where testInfo is the jquery widget I created.
   width: 300,
   title: 'Test Info',
   content:{name: 'test 2', status: 'FINISHED',region: 'Washington DC'}
});
```

My html:

```
<div class="info loadtestinfo" id="testinfoWidget">
<ul class="contentBox boxHighlight" id = "contentBox"></ul></div>
```

And my underscore.js template:

```
<script type = "test/javascript" id = "usageList">
`<li class="contentBoxHeader"><%- title %></li>`
  `<li class="contentBoxContent">`   
           `<table class="simpleTable" id ="simpleTable">` 

           <tr>
            <td class="label">Name:</td>
            <td class="value"><%- content.name %></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="vertical-align: top;">Status:</td>
                <td class="value">
                    <span id="test_state"><%- content.status %></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Region:</td>

                <td class="value"><%- content.region %></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Start:</td>
                <td class="value"><%- content.start %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">End:</td>
                <td class="value"><%- content.end %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</li>
```

I would like to use the above underscore template and render the o/p as below:

```
Title: Test Info
Name: test2
Region: Washnigton DC
Status: FINISHED.
```

Does any one have any ideas???

Comment: What happens when you give your object to the template as-is?

Comment: If you show us what exactly you're doing then we might be able to point out where you're going wrong. A demo (complete with sample data) on jsfiddle.net would also help.